# Is it possible to use pyflink on windows?

Tags: apache-flink, pyflink

Has anyone ever had success running using python and windows with flink?

I'm trying the following command:

`.\bin\pyflink.bat examples\python\WordCount.py`

and getting the following error

```
Starting execution of program
Usage: ./bin/pyflink<2/3>.[sh/bat] <pathToScript>[ <pathToPackage1>[ <pathToPackageX]][ - <parameter1>[ <parameterX>]]

The program didn't contain a Flink job. Perhaps you forgot to call execute() on the execution environment.
```

Comment: Please share some more details about what you have tried (version numbers etc) and also the full error you are getting.

Comment: Exact command being executed and resulting error added above. Version is Version: 1.3.2, Commit ID: 0399bee on Windows 10 x64.

Answer (score 0):

> The program didn't contain a Flink job. Perhaps you forgot to call
>   execute() on the execution environment.

This looks like you forgot to add

`env.execute(local=True)`

in case you are running it locally. Without this the flink job wouldnt be able to execute. You can find more information with this [simple example program](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/batch/python.html#example-program)

Comment: I've tried it with the simple example program you mentioned and with the local=True parameter. What I've noticed is that the filename provided to pyflink is irrelevant. I always get the same error. I could type ```pyflink nonExistentFile.py``` and I'd get the same error.

Comment: I am facing same issue. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I got this information in Win10. Maybe it is not supported at present.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the following release-1.11, PyFlink will support windows in local mode. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-12717